# moving from localhost to production codeigniter project

Tags: php, codeigniter, server

I upload my codeigniter website on the server. After uploading website on server in website some images are showing and some images are not displaying properly..also some text is showing out of boarder ..

I used filezila to upload file from local to server.

here is .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /beta/lalcoresidency 

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css|docs|js|system)
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /beta/lalcoresidency/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

my config.php

```
 $config['base_url'] = 'https://www.lalcoresidency.com/beta/lalcoresidency/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
$config['url_suffix'] = '';
$config['language'] = 'english';
$config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';
$config['enable_hooks'] = FALSE;
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';
```

here is my website link

```
https://www.lalcoresidency.com/beta/lalcoresidency/home
```

Please help me to find out the solution .I tried lot but didn't  get the solution..please help

Comment: Not quite sure what images arent reloading but your google font for example is denied because your server is running on HTTPS and you request the google fonts over HTTP. To fix that you have to include the google fonts over HTTPS aswell. That results in a JS error which probably causes your other issues aswell.

Comment: how i resolve this xatenev...please help

Comment: Include the google fonts over HTTPS.

Comment: There is any link or i changed http to https in code

Comment: font problem is solved what about the images and all layout ..

Comment: on which page your images are not loading?

Comment: Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.lalcoresidency.com/beta/lalcoresidency/home' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false'. - Use your developer tools (F12) and open console. Fix all errors that appear inside that.

Answer (score 1):

your server is running on HTTPS and you request the google fonts over HTTP..change all http to https.

example:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

to

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```